# Make Byebug finish executing without exiting Pry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pry, byebug

When I set a breakpoint with Byebug in Rails, I sometimes want it to finish executing, but the guide on github says to use `exit` which also exits Pry.  Typing `continue` repeatedly can be annoying if the breakpoint is  in a loop.

Is there anyway to stop byebug without exiting the Rails console?

Comment: You can try the command "abort", it will abort the current execution

Answer (score 35):

When running `byebug` under the Rails console or in Rails' server I usually quit only byebug by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

The catch with this approach is, if you do this in Rails' server then Byebug will not stop and debug the next time it hits a `byebug` statement in your code anywhere. But it works perfectly in the Rails console.

Answer (score 7):

Try `!!!`. It works on [pry gem](https://github.com/pry/pry), but not sure if it does on byebug.

Answer (score 2):

Well this isn't the most elegant solution but it works for me so far.

If you have a base controller in your rails application you can add an accessor to hold a variable saying whether you want debugging to happen or not:

```
attr_accessor :debugging
```

Then add/modify initializer to set the variable to true on each request (or each time there is an instance created for that object):

```
def initialize
  @debugging=true
  super
end
```

And finally, always use the byebug call with a conditional wherever you want this behavior:

```
byebug if debugging
```

Then when you are at the IRB console and you want to exit the debugger but continue executing the code you just set the variable:

```
@debugging=false; finish
```

You could even encapsulate this in a helper or do some OOP magic but this is a good starting point. Nice thing is that if you repeat the request you'll get the standard behavior again unless you set the variable to `false` again.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to exit a loop try `skip`.

It'll runs until the next breakpoint as long as it is different from the current one.

Then, once you are out of the loop you can `continue`.

Answer (score 1):

Typing `finish` in the console exits byebug, without closing pry/rails console/rails server.

*Ctrl + D* also works.

Comment: `finish` helps, but it doesn't really do what you say, somehow it gets deeper in the code...

Answer (score 0):

Go to your code and remove  `byebug` and save, then in the buybug terminal write `continue` then press enter.

Tadaaa your app will continue and you will exit byebug all without closing your app.

Answer (score 0):

Try `continue` or `finish`

Source: https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#resuming-execution

Answer (score -1):

Remove "debugger from your code and type in "finish" in console

Comment: Tried removing 'byebug' from the code but it kept breaking afterwards anyway as if it were there.  Same behavior trying 'continue' and 'finish' commands.

Comment: This won't work. The code won't be reloaded until you exit the console.

Comment: Not sure what the removing debuger is for, but typing `finish` in the byebug interface exited byebug without closing the rails console.

Answer (score -1):

```sh
(byebug) quit
Really quit? (y/n) y
user ~
```

The only one that works quickly and without issues for me so far.

Comment: This also quits the whole irb/rails console.