# How to continue without breakpoints in Byebug

Tags: ruby, byebug

Using the `byebug` gem gives me the ability to `continue` until the next breakpoint:

```
(byebug) help

  break      -- Sets breakpoints in the source code
  catch      -- Handles exception catchpoints
  condition  -- Sets conditions on breakpoints
  continue   -- Runs until program ends, hits a breakpoint or reaches a line
  delete     -- Deletes breakpoints
  disable    -- Disables breakpoints or displays
  display    -- Evaluates expressions every time the debugger stops
  down       -- Moves to a lower frame in the stack trace
  edit       -- Edits source files
  enable     -- Enables breakpoints or displays
  finish     -- Runs the program until frame returns
  frame      -- Moves to a frame in the call stack
  help       -- Helps you using byebug
  history    -- Shows byebug's history of commands
  info       -- Shows several informations about the program being debugged
  interrupt  -- Interrupts the program
  irb        -- Starts an IRB session
  kill       -- Sends a signal to the current process
  list       -- Lists lines of source code
  method     -- Shows methods of an object, class or module
  next       -- Runs one or more lines of code
  pry        -- Starts a Pry session
  ps         -- Evaluates an expression and prettyprints & sort the result
  quit       -- Exits byebug
  restart    -- Restarts the debugged program
  save       -- Saves current byebug session to a file
  set        -- Modifies byebug settings
  show       -- Shows byebug settings
  source     -- Restores a previously saved byebug session
  step       -- Steps into blocks or methods one or more times
  thread     -- Commands to manipulate threads
  tracevar   -- Enables tracing of a global variable
  undisplay  -- Stops displaying all or some expressions when program stops
  untracevar -- Stops tracing a global variable
  up         -- Moves to a higher frame in the stack trace
  var        -- Shows variables and its values
  where      -- Displays the backtrace
```

I looked all over and I cannot find a way to "continue without breakpoints". The only way I can think of is to remove or comment the `byebug` statements, quit with `q!` and restart the test.

How can I continue without stopping at other `byebug` statements in Ruby?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just found out in the [code](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug/blob/e1fb8209d56922f7bafd128af84e61568b6cd6a7/lib/byebug/attacher.rb), that you can stop byebug altogether using:

```
Byebug.mode = :off
```

You can't turn it back on, since it won't attach on itself any more, but this is handy, e.g. when just debugging a script that you want to finish running.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Pairs nicely with a temporary before_action in the application controller to turn it back on with every request.

Comment: is there any other way to achieve it ? like --disable-all or something like that ?

Answer (score 23):

You can use `continue!` or alias `c!` since byebug 11.0.0, released on February 15, 2019.

See this PR https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug/pull/524

If you are working with Rails, you may wanna reset it back on new request, than you can add a filter:

```
# application_controller.rb
 before_action do
    if defined?(Byebug) && Byebug.mode == :off && Rails.env.development?
      Byebug.mode = nil
    end
 end
```

Comment: This is the answer. c will continue and break at break point. c! will continue ignoring break points.

Answer (score 6):

A `byebug` method call in your code is not a 'breakpoint' (thinking of the references to breakpoint in the help output).

As per the help output, `breakpoint`s can be disabled with the `disable` command. But that does not solve your problem because the next `byebug` will pause execution again.

Since `byebug` is just a method call, you can make it conditional:

```
byebug if SomeModule.byebug?
```

Then, in SomeModule, you could use a global variable to toggle it on/off. You'd either have to do that on all your calls to byebug, or you could monkey-patch the byebug method to do the same, `alias_method_chain` or something similar.

"[Make Byebug finish executing without exiting Pry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30627186/make-byebug-finish-executing-without-exiting-pry/35545808#35545808)" is a similar answer.